# Unidentified identification

Tags: identification, houseplants, tropical

I have searched the internet using 4 different plant ID. Sites and have not been able to identify this beautiful plant growing in a dental office. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
CD.

---

- [image: Heading]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the leaf shape, growth habit, and glossiness, I'm getting a "croton"  (either a hybrid member of the enormous *[Croton](http://sosplantcare.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Meijer-gardens_croton.jpg)* genus or one from the the less common (to me, at least) *[Codaeium variegatum](https://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/g/1/a/PLANT-WORLD-Croton-Plant-Codaeium-SDL598503404-1-cafd9.jpeg)* species). The yellow variegation is more in line with *C. variegatum* than any of the hyrids I've seen, though.

If I'm correct, then the plant is being grown in too much shade/not enough indirect light, which is why the leaves are so green. The site given in the first link ([sosplantcare.com/croton-care/](https://sosplantcare.com/croton-care/)) confirms this and includes [this photo](http://sosplantcare.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/croton-2.jpg) showing that effect.